# Wrapping a legacy widget for ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function `gauge(dom_element, value, max)` which draws a gauge (with a needle) within an element (using canvas).

The widget has no update method, you must call it again to remove the old widget and draw a new widget with a new value.

How can I wrap this so that the function is called to recreate the gauge whenever the ReactJS state `value` is changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this pattern for pretty much any plugin you're wrapping; some require a bit more when they have events, etc.

```
var Gauge = React.createClass({

  // handle the first mount and updates
  // in this case there's no difference between init and update
  // with the gauge widget, so these just delegate to updateGauge
  componentDidMount: function(){ 
    this.updateGauge(this.props.value, this.props.max); 
  },
  componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps){ 
    if (nextProps.value !== this.props.value) {
      this.updateGauge(nextProps.value, nextProps.max);
    }
  },

  // render an empty div, which will be `this.getDOMNode()` in the following function
  render: function(){ return <div />; },

  // actually tell the plugin to run
  updateGauge: function(value, max){
    gauge(this.getDOMNode(), value, max);
  },

  // clean up after the gauge widget
  // sometimes you don't need anything here, but if you do
  // you'll get a nice error from react when it's unmounted :-)
  componentWillUnmount: function(){
    // ...
  }
});
```

Comment: Should the value be a property, rather than state?

Comment: @chrisdew yes, it should.  This is just a wrapper for your gauge which you can use in components that have state, e.g. `<Gauge value={this.state.x} />`